# How to drop functions with dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, dynamic-sql

We need to drop all functions for a specific database ( by code ). There are a lot of questions for dropping functions but all anwsers fail to drop functions with dependency.
One popular anwser is following:

```
/* Drop all functions */ 
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(254) 
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128)

SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 ORDER BY [name]) 
SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)

WHILE @name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP FUNCTION [' + @schema + '].[' + RTRIM(@name) +']' 
    EXEC (@SQL) 
    PRINT 'Dropped Function: ' + @name 
    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE [type] IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT') AND category = 0 AND [name] > @name ORDER BY [name]) 
    SELECT @schema = (SELECT TOP 1 schema_name(schema_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE [name] = @name)
END 
GO
```

How can i adjust it to ensure it is deleted in correct order ( and doesnt fail because of Msg 3729 )

Comment: What you looking to do when  there is a dependency on that function?

Comment: @Larnu delete this dependency first, you can assume that all functions have only dependencies to other functions

Comment: You can put EXEC(@SQL)  into a TRY CATCH block. The execution will continue . You should  modify  the loop as well.

Comment: _you can assume ..._ A rather broad assumption that generally doesn't make much sense. The only reason to write a function is to use it in other code "units" - like procedures, triggers, views, and application code that you do not seem to have considered. Functions calling other functions is also unusual IME. Think and test carefully - and perhaps give some thought to how your organization designs code at a higher level.

Comment: @SMor well yes it would be great if the script can delete all user functions ( like procedures, triggers, views and functions ) in the correct order. but to simplify this conversion and the solution, it would be enough to delete functions in their dependency order - all other things would be next step.

Comment: @Serg execute the 'drop functions' procedure in loop until no error occour would be a first solution - i keep this in mind as backup but would prefer an approch without throwing and catching exceptions^^

Comment: You can't just keep trying to drop all the functions because, as mentioned previously, the dependencies might live in other object types, like procedures, views, etc. If a trigger references a function you're trying to drop, think about what behavior you want: drop the trigger first?

Comment: If I wanted to do this, I'd write a recursive query against one of the system views that tracks object dependencies. I like sys.sql_expression_dependencies. The goal would be to create an ordered list of what objects need to be dropped. That is, drop those objects on which nothing depends, then objects whose only dependencies were just dropped, etc until you're done.

Comment: @BenThul thanks for the tip, didnt know this view, its exactly what is was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` to find references to a function.

So you just retrieve all functions which have no references, drop them, then loop again.

```sql
DECLARE @maxRuns int = 10;

WHILE (@maxRuns > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
        SELECT STRING_AGG(
            'DROP FUNCTION ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ';', '
'
          )
        FROM sys.objects o
        JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        WHERE o.type IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT')
          AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name), 'OBJECT')
          )
    );

    IF (@sql IS NULL)
        BREAK;

    PRINT @sql; -- for testing
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    SET @maxRuns -= 1;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03bfbd3cf3fdfded32d08affbfaa4479)